# Talk in the iPhone mic and play that sound in the Speaker simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I got a requirement from One of my client is that We have to say some thing in the iPhone mic and that sound (Which we have speak in the mic) has to come from the iPhone speaker simultaneously(Without any delay.).

Example: In the open meetings if the speaker say something in the mic,that sound comes out from the speakers without any delay. I have to do the samething

We have to do it using `Objective-c`. I have been doing research since last one day. Could any one please guide me how to do this.Any ideas/suggestions could be very grateful.

Comment: Could anyone please tell me why it is down voted?

Comment: @Ermaidu and anyone interested: Lately I've been pissed off by members of SO that like to think themselves as the ultimate judges, and they downvote for the most stupid reasons, instead of being constructive and minding their own businesses.

Comment: Just for the record I didn't down vote.

Comment: @CGRasterMouse I'm sorry, it's nothing personal, and certainly nothing against you or any downvoters. It's just that I feel sometimes users don't realize it takes a big effort to help someone online, and, for example today, this guy's comment at my answer below, he has probably never worked with Audio Units, and has probably never compiled and studied the sample I suggested, yet he dares to make a striking critique.

Comment: I agree this is a weak function of SO. Downvoting a question should maybe incur a loss of rep like down voting an answer. Or a comment should be mandatory when down voting.

Comment: @CGRasterMouse downvoting an answer indeed incurs a 1 point rep loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any experience programming with audio in iOS it's not that difficult, but if you've never programmed anything like this prepare to read some considerable amount of documentation.

What you need can be achieved using [Audio Units](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH1-SW1). There are some Apple's examples, like [Audio Mixer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210).

In short, Audio units are little pieces that you connect together to create an Audio Graph. You need to connect and Input Audio Unit routed to the microphone to an Ouput Audio Unit routed to the speakers.

At this point, it's hard for me (and for anyone) to say anything else on this subject that is not in the docs. Maybe when you make some progress your questions will be more specific.

Comment: To anyone who downvoted, can I get some feedback?

Comment: Have you read the question correctly? The user is asking for live sound. Audio mixer is for recorded files only not for live audio , user is asking for unsaved audio files. He have edited the question

Comment: @Tendulkar Audio Mixer is an example that uses two recordings, but THAT IS JUST AN EXAMPLE of how to use Audio Units, don't expect an example to do exactly what you want. If in the mixer you switch one of the recordings for an Input Audio Unit you have a mixer with an input from the microphone!

Comment: I think this answer is too broad and high level and have a hard time believing this was accepted.  A more detailed response should explain that 0 latency is impossible as hotpaw2 stated in his answer.  A small latency is reasonable.  The approach should discuss to use a particular audio unit called remote io.  The way it is solved is by using a remote io unit and providing the microphone samples (remote IO input bus 1) directly to the speaker (remote IO output bus 0).

Answer (score 1):

Zero delay is not possible.  The minimum Audio Unit buffer latency on most iOS devices in 5.8 milliseconds; and there is no faster public API connected to the mic or speaker.

If latency of that order is acceptable, then try using the RemoteIO Audio Unit for audio record and play, and request the minimum buffer time and size using the AVAudioSession API.

iOS Audio Units use a pure C API, as all the higher level Objective C APIs are slower, and thus unsuitable for low latency audio.